# Interface methods that need to accept ambiguous arguments?

Tags: c++, lua, luaplus

Wasn't sure how to word the problem for the title of the post correctly.  Here is the issue I am experiencing.  We have an interface that will be implemented by our `LuaStateManager` class to register functions to a `LuaPlus::LuaState`. The issue is that these functions could potentially have any signature.

LuaPlus allows you to register any function with its `LuaObject::RegisterDirect` method. It can do this because it uses templates. However, we have to encapsulate the `LuaState` in an interface which has pure virtual functions.

So our idea was to have a function that `LuaStateManager` will implement:

```
IScriptState::RegisterFunction( /* What should go here? */ )
```

As you can probably see, though, there is no way to specify what type of argument should be passed to this function as it could potentially be any function signature.  We cant use templates like LuaPlus does because virtual functions cannot be templated.  We can't template the entire `LuaStateManager` class or `IScriptState` interface either because for each type of function passed it would generate a wholly new script state and none of the functions would reside together.

How have problems like this been solved in the past? Currently we are going with a brute force method that just throws all our exports in a struct that users can derive from and fill out.  That way they will know which scripting language they are using and be able to directly use `LuaStateManager` instead of the `IScriptState` interface, but that is totally a sloppy 'hack' solution.

Comment: Can you use a combination of template-function which does the work depending on the exact arguments and a called virtual function which does the rest?